# My program empties my list and I don't understand why

Tags: python

```
def is_number(file):
    cList = file.read()
    chars=len(cList)
    t = 0
    retlist=[]

    while t<chars:
        try:
            int(cList[t])
            int(cList[t + 1])
            x = (cList[t] + cList[t + 1])
            retlist.append(int(x))
            t+=1
        except ValueError:
            try:
                x = int(cList[t])
                retlist.append(x)
            except ValueError:
                pass

        t+=1


    retlist.sort()
    return retlist
```

Ok so this is my code that reads a file and takes all the numbers up to 99 and adds them to a list. But when i return it the list it's suddenly empty for some reason, can't figure out why please help!

```
def main():

    while True:

        try:
            f = input("Enter the name of the file: ")
            file = open(f + ".txt", "r")
            is_number(file)
            break

        except IOError:
            pass

        print("The file %s could not be found, try again!" % (f))


    numList = is_number(file)
    print(numList)
```

main()

The code that calls the function.

Comment: Please add the input and what you are expecting from this function

Comment: You return `realist` not `retlist`. Is this a typo, or do you actually have a `realist` somewhere else in your code?

Comment: Just to be sure, did you copy the code exactly? Because you are returning ``realist``, which doesn't exist.

Comment: When you want other people to read your code, there should be spaces in it. like `int(clist[t + 1))`

Comment: Sorry I am very new at this.. Give me a sec.

Comment: `return map(int, re.findall(r'\d\d', myfile.read()))` doesn't answer your question but it does solve your problem.

Comment: The realist thing is just a typo that happened when I posted it here.

Comment: @Almo -- that's quite a nit -- and one that I'm not 100% sure that I agree with.  PEP 8 only suggests that you use the same amount of space on either side.

Comment: @mgilson It's an example. Code should have spaces around operators, or it's very hard to read. I'm not the only person I know who will ignore a question on SO if the code is too hard to read. Just trying to help him have the best chance of getting help.

Comment: @Almo:  The spaces are often omitted in arguments to function calls.  Brackets *feel* like a function call.  PEP 8 even includes this as recommended `ham[lower+offset : upper+offset]`.

Comment: run it through debugger or put some print statements and see what's happening.

Comment: Ok so the point of this is that the program should read a .txt file and then find all the numbers and add them to a list. An if I print the list directly in is_number it works like a charm but somehow then i return it its' suddenly empty..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python (and most other languages) have the notion of a "file pointer" -- it's a reference to some location in the file. All reading and writing starts at the file pointer. For example, if the file pointer is at the beginning of the file, calling `read()` will read the entire file. If the file pointer were moved, say, 100 characters forward, calling `read()` would skip those first 100 characters.

Reading will always advance the file pointer to immediately after the point it stopped reading. So, for example, if you asked it to read only 100 bytes, the file pointer will advance 100 bytes and the next read would read from there.

In your code, `is_number` accepts a file handle and immediately reads the entire contents of the file. When it does this, the file pointer is moved to the end of the file. After your loop exits, you call `is_number` again on the last file that was opened. Since the file pointer is at the end of the file and hasn't been moved, there's nothing to read so `numList` is set to the empty string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Gave me some more understanding in all this! As you may tell I'm still a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Bryan's answer, you can use the `seek()` method of files to restart reading from the beginning. For example, if `f` is the name of your file handle, `f.seek(0)` will point to the beginning of the file.

Comment: This is better left as a comment on Bryan's answer since it's not a full answer.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Unfortunately don't yet have enough reputation points to comment :-(